# Github uncommited changes message

Tags: git

I am trying to learn git using a dummy folder I created and using an actual production git repo.
I dont understand under what circumstance the below error is thrown:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        index.html
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

The below is the sequence of actions I take on my dummy git folder:

```
PS C:\Users\thepav\Desktop\git project> git status
On branch feature-a
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature-a'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   index.html

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

    PS C:\Users\thepav\Desktop\git project> git checkout main
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
            index.html
    Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
    Aborting
```

I am trying to reproduce this same behaviour in the Prod git repo by modifying a file but this is what I get:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   application/ice.ini.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git checkout master
M       application/ice.ini.php
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Question is why the prod git repo doesn't throw the error?

Comment: When you try to checkout/switch, git does a test on files that have **uncommitted** changes in the working tree. If the files are _exactly the same_ between `HEAD` and where you want to go (`HEAD` does **not** mean the file as you have it on the working tree, it means the file as it is in the _commit_ that you are standing on), then git allows the checkout to happen and the files are kept the way you have them in the working tree. However, if those files with uncommitted changes are different between `HEAD` and where you are going, then git rejects the checkout.

Answer (score 0):

On the first scenario, you modified `index.html` locally but there are also differences in the repository between the versions of `index.html` from your current branch (`feature-a`) and the branch you want to switch to (`main`). `git checkout` should replace your local `index.html` with the version from branch `main` but that will destroy your local changes (they were not persisted in a commit yet). This is why it shows the warning and aborts the checkout.

On the second scenario, the file modified locally (`application/ice.ini.php`) does not differ between branches in the repository and it is not modified on checkout.

On `git checkout`, Git changes the `HEAD` reference to point to the target branch then it applies the differences between the old branch and the new branch to the index and to the local working tree.

---

Back in 2019, on [version 2.23](https://github.blog/2019-08-16-highlights-from-git-2-23/), Git introduced two new commands, [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/) and [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore/). Each of them does some of what `git checkout` does. They were introduced because `git checkout` does too many unrelated things, depending on how it is invoked.

It is recommended to use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/) to switch branches.

*(Under the hood and besides the differences in the command line, `git switch` works the same as `git checkout` invoked with a branch name and without file paths as arguments. The behaviour described in the question does not change. It is just easier to understand its purpose.)*

Comment: Sorry but doesnt work for me.. I synced the index.html in both branches - main and feature-a.. Made some local changes but still seeing the same error message.

Comment: Ok, so still trying to get my head around this. The files were sync only on git website not locally.. did a git pull origin in both branches and it makes sense now